# What is the alternative of datefromparts in Presto (AWS Athena)

Tags: sql, date, presto, amazon-athena

What is the best performance alternative of datefromparts SQL function in AWS Athena (Presto DB)?

The use case is:

I have the date parts (i.e. the day, month, and year) and need the date from these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically use [`parse_date()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse), with the proper format specifiers. If your date is in ISO format, you can directly use [`from_iso_date()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_date) (or [`from_iso_timestamp()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp)).

On the other hand, if you need to extract dates part, you can use [`extract()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#extract), like:

```
extract(hour from current_timestamp)
```

Note that Presto also offers a full range of short function name that correspond to the possible extraction parts: `year()`, `quarter()`, `month()`, ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, I am looking for the opposite function, I want to get a date from its parts, for example, I have the day, moth, and year and need the date from that, one option I had in mind was to put the parts into a string and parse them back, this seemed very counter intuitive .

Comment: @Sakher: I think that's the way to go here... I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate, really appreciate it!